# Find previous value of drop down list on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have drop down list declared like :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDown" width="300" CssClass="textboxda" 
AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" onmousewheel="return false;" />
```

Drop down list change method

```
myDropDown.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "return OnChange();");


function OnChange()
{
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var sel = $j(this).prevAll("#myDropDown:first"),
      val = sel.val(),
      text = sel.find(':selected').text(); 

    alert(text);
}
```

I am populating this drop down dynamically.

I am fetching the last/previously selected text of the drop down, but this is not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: `id` in  a HTML page is supposed to be unique

Comment: it is unique..I have given an example here..

Comment: Can you give your DOM structure

Comment: in DOM also I find the same function only...what exactly needed from DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myDropDown.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "return OnChange(this);");
```

after that you can put another attribute for current selected item

```
myDropDown.Attributes.Add("previous", "your default selected value");
```

after that your function like this

```
function OnChange(args)
{

 var previousVal=$(args).attr('previous');
var newVal=$(args).find(':selected'); 
alert(previousVal);
alert(newVal);
$(args).attr('previous',newVal);
}
```

Comment: It displays like 0.00...I need text...so I made text()...now its showing all items of drop down..

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="countries">
<option value="">Select country</option>
<option value="68">Russia</option>
<option value="20">United States</option>
<option value="73">Albania</option>
<option value="143">Algeria</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countries').on('change', function() {
       var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');   
       console.log('Prev = ', $selected.prev().text());
       console.log('Next = ', $selected.next().text());    
       console.log('Last = ', $(this).find('option:last').text()); 
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S85rY/2/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<select id="countries" previous="" onchange="countrychange(this)">
<option value="">Select country</option>
<option value="68">Russia</option>
<option value="20">United States</option>
<option value="73">Albania</option>
<option value="143">Algeria</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function  countrychange(args){
    var previousVal=$(args).attr('previous');
    var newVal=$(args).find(':selected'); 
    alert(previousVal);
    alert(newVal);
    $(args).attr('previous',newVal);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want jquery? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/3vRs9/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
        alert('Changed selected: '+$('#mySelect option:selected').val());   
    });
});
```

Comment: This gives the current selection, not what it was prior to being changed